# Formatting HTML Source using Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, code-formatting

Is there any Ruby library available to format the HTML source. By formatting I mean removing the extra spacing, apply proper indentation etc.

I am already using Hpricot for parsing HTML. It would be nice if Hpricot could do this job. But I am not stick with Hpricot for the formatting stuff.

Thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out this Ruby interface to the HTML Tidy library.](http://tidy.rubyforge.org/classes/Tidy.html)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll have a look at it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Extra spacing and formatting don't really matter in HTML, so regardless of the formatting and white space, the browser should display the code as the same.

Comment: I agree. But consider this as a unique requirement. We need to achieve this somehow. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I also like clean, and predictive html because of unit testing. Whitespaces and newlines always hard to take care in string equals operations